# how to redirect to another web server from nginx

Tags: php, node.js, nginx

i have tried to redirect to php and node.js from nginx. this is my nginx code

```
server {

       listen 8060;
       server_name mydomain;
       access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.log;
       location /
       {
            proxy_pass http://mydomain;
       }
       location /node {

       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
       proxy_pass http://mydomain/;
       proxy_redirect off;
      }
   }
```

when i run localhost:8060 in browser it is redirecting to localhost:70. from here added /index.html in browser it is showing that html page.i have written on ajax call within that html page. so when i click submit button ajax will be called and then send request to php and getting response from php within success function of ajax.it is working fine.and then again i am redirecting to nginx from that success function itself this is that code

```
               $.ajax(
                    {
                    url:"service/lpage.php",
                    type:"GET",
                    contentType: "application/json",   
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{"uname":user,"password":pass},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                            if(data.token)
                            {

                                    window.location="http://mydomain:8060/node?token="+data.token;
                            }
                    },
                     error: function(data,statusCode) { 
                    alert('Error ' + statusCode); 
                    } 
            });
```

again i am redirecting to node.js from nginx by using this  proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:4000/; yes it is redirect but when it is redirecting to node.js i am rendering one html .so js and css files are in localhost:4000 but it is seeking that library 127.0.0.1:8060 so i am getting Not found error in my firebug.how to resolve this?